# FXML: Binding to controller

Tags: javafx, binding, fxml

Is it possible to bind in FXML just like in xaml to the controller to a class varibale. What I am doing is:

FXML

```
<ComboBox fx:id="searchField" 
                    HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" editable="true" />
<GridPane hgap="5" vgap="5">
    <Label text="Nom" />
    <Label text="$selecteClient.name"
        GridPane.columnIndex="1" />

    <Label GridPane.rowIndex="1" text="tél" />
    <Label text="$electedClient.phoneNumber"
        GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
<GridPane/>
```

Controler:

```
private final List<Client> clients = FXCollections.observableArrayList(ImportingDataService.importClients());
@FXML
private Client selectedClient;

@FXML
private ComboBox<Client> searchField;

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    // Set appDtat client id so it refreshes when client is changed
    this.appState.clientViewClientIDProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        selectedClient = ImportingDataService.importClient(newValue.longValue());

    });

    // Set up combo box
    setUpComboBox();

}
private void setUpComboBox() {
    searchField.getItems().addAll(clients);
    UtilService.autoCompleteComboBoxPlus(searchField, (typedText, client) -> client.getName().contains(typedText));

    // Handle selecting clients
    searchField.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        selectedClient = ImportingDataService.importClient(newValue.getId());
    });
}
```

My `Client` class is a class that has the `String` fields `name` and `phoneNumber`. and the `ImportingDataService.importClient` is for importing data from database, they work just fine (I placed breakpoints and checked that). The problem is that I don't know why the client `Label`s do not update when I change the selection of the `ComboBox`, while the `selectedClient` does change. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are multiple reasons for this:

1. A simple field is not observable.
2. You do not include `controller` in the expression binding.
3. There is a typo here `$selecteClient.name` and here `$electedClient.phoneNumber`.
4. The whole expression needs to be wrapped inside `{}` to be bound, not just set.

You could e.g. fix it like this:

**Controller**

```
private final ObjectProperty<Client> selectedClient = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(initialClient);

public final Client getSelectedClient() {
    return this.selectedClient.get();
}

public final void setSelectedClient(Client value) {
    this.selectedClient.set(value);
}

public final ObjectProperty<Client> selectedClientProperty() {
    return this.selectedClient;
}

...

// selectedClient = ImportingDataService.importClient(newValue.getId());
setSelectedClient(ImportingDataService.importClient(newValue.getId()));
```

**fxml**

```xml
<ComboBox fx:id="searchField" 
                    HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" editable="true" />
<GridPane hgap="5" vgap="5">
    <Label text="Nom" />
    <Label text="${controller.selectedClient.name}"
        GridPane.columnIndex="1" />

    <Label GridPane.rowIndex="1" text="tél" />
    <Label text="${controller.selectedClient.phoneNumber}"
        GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
<GridPane/>
```

**Client**

```
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getPhoneNumber() {
    return phoneNumber;
}
```

(or something similar)

Comment: This is a nice complete answer, but it does work with only fixing the typos. The observable object is not necessary. Thanks.

Comment: I take back what I said. it's not working. in fact I add few labels bound them to other attributes but this to using the combo box selection model, and in this manner it works with no observable object. other wise it does not.